# Unable to figure out brand of shower trim

Tags: shower, trim

Noobie here.

I am having issues 1) figuring out how to remove this shower trim - didn't see any screws to remove and there are no logos anywhere on the outside.

and 2) figuring out the brand!

Wondering if anyone has seen this before. The way it works is that pulling the lever down starts the water, and turning it side to side changes the temperature. It has a ball-in-socket type of mechanism.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: #2 almost impossible unless someone who sees it has the same/similar one.  The trim on the wall might be just attached to the caulk/sealant or might be on clips if no screw holding it.

Comment: the triangle icon on the handle may be a clue ... the greek capital letter *delta* is a triangle ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=greek+delta&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: @jsotola it could be just an arrow point up

Comment: Unscrew the shower diverter knob, cut the seal around the wall cover and remove the cover